# ODA X8-2M crossrestore with TDE wallet fails with: DCS-10001:Internal error encountered: failed to open the tde password based wallet

Tags: oracle, restore, transparent-data-encryption, oracle-19c, multi-tenant

We are trying to crossrestore a TDE encrypted Oracle Database 19.12 on a new ODA X8-2M.
TDE wallet has been successfully backedup (`odacli create-backup -in CDBET015 -c TDEWallet`) and transferred to the new ODA to the filesystem (not ASM).

```
[oracle@oda-host tdewallet]$ ls -ltr
total 72
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oracle oinstall  341 Feb 25 13:23 logfile.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oracle oinstall 5835 Feb 25 13:23 ewallet_202202241425400934_CDB.p12
```

Crossrestore with SBT-Tape was successful and RMAN completed the restore and the recovery. However the `odacli register-database` was not yet started.
We tried to restore the wallet first, because it is not part of the rman crossrestore.

```
odacli restore-tdewallet -in CDBET015 -tl /u01/NFS_TDE/backup/CDB/tdewallet/ewallet.p12
```

The restore of the TDE wallet fails because the new ODA does not know the new database.
The ODA need to register the newly restored Database first. This fails because it does not have the wallet.

```
odacli register-database -c OLTP -s odb1 -sn CDB -t SI –tp
Enter SYS, SYSTEM and PDB Admin user password:
Retype SYS, SYSTEM and PDB Admin user password:
Enter TDE wallet password:
Retype TDE wallet password:
```

Job details:

```
odacli describe-job   -i "7e60dc6f-0c69-4bb8-8205-bee6f6276b19"

Job details
----------------------------------------------------------------
                     ID:  7e60dc6f-0c69-4bb8-8205-bee6f6276b19
            Description:  Database service registration with db service name: CDBET015
                 Status:  Failure
                Created:  February 25, 2022 4:04:21 PM CET
                Message:  DCS-10001:Internal error encountered: failed to open the tde password based wallet for database : CDB.ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT SET KEYSTORE OPEN identified by ******** container=all
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28367: wallet does not exist

Task Name                                Start Time                          End Time                            Status
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------
database Service registration            February 25, 2022 4:04:22 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:05:54 PM CET    Failure
database Service registration            February 25, 2022 4:04:22 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:05:54 PM CET    Failure
TDE parameter validate at destination    February 25, 2022 4:04:22 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:04:22 PM CET    Success
Enable OMF parameters                    February 25, 2022 4:04:23 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:04:23 PM CET    Success
Setting db character set                 February 25, 2022 4:04:23 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:04:24 PM CET    Success
Move Spfile to right location            February 25, 2022 4:04:24 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:04:33 PM CET    Success
Enable DbSizing Template                 February 25, 2022 4:04:33 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:05:32 PM CET    Success
Copy Pwfile to Shared Storage            February 25, 2022 4:05:32 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:05:39 PM CET    Success
Add Startup Trigger to Open all PDBS     February 25, 2022 4:05:39 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:05:40 PM CET    Success
Running DataPatch                        February 25, 2022 4:05:40 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:05:53 PM CET    Success
configuring TDE                          February 25, 2022 4:05:53 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:05:54 PM CET    Failure
Opening wallet                           February 25, 2022 4:05:53 PM CET    February 25, 2022 4:05:54 PM CET    Failure
```

How to make the wallet accessible to the database/ODA?

Answer (score 0):

A workround could be:

```
alter system set wallet_root='/stage/backup/wallet/orabackups/xxxxxxx/database/3205039394/CDB/tdewallet/' scope=spfile;
 
     
SQL> ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT SET KEYSTORE open IDENTIFIED BY "xxxxx";
 
keystore altered.
 
 
SQL> administer key management set key identified by "xxxxx" with backup;
 
keystore altered.
 
 
SQL>  administer key management create AUTO_LOGIN keystore from keystore '/stage/backup/wallet/orabackups/hostname/database/3205039394/CDB/tdewallet/tde' identified by xxxxxxx;
 
keystore altered.
 
Startup force
 
SQL> select * from v$encryption_wallet;
 
WRL_TYPE             WRL_PARAMETER                  STATUS                         WALLET_TYPE          WALLET_OR KEYSTORE FULLY_BAC     CON_ID
-------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------------- --------- -------- --------- ----------
FILE                 /stage/backup/wallet/orabackup OPEN                           AUTOLOGIN            SINGLE    NONE     NO                 1
                     s/hostname/database/320
                     5039394/CDB/tdewallet//td
                     e/
 
FILE                                                OPEN                           AUTOLOGIN            SINGLE    UNITED   NO                 2
FILE                                                OPEN                           AUTOLOGIN            SINGLE    UNITED   NO             

3

odacli register-database -c OLTP -s odb1 -sn CDB -t SI -tp
Enter SYS, SYSTEM and PDB Admin user password:
Retype SYS, SYSTEM and PDB Admin user password:
Enter TDE wallet password:
Retype TDE wallet password:
 
odacli describe-job "110a5246-f239-4fab-aad2-c001ae68c2e7"
 
Job details
----------------------------------------------------------------
                     ID:  110a5246-f239-4fab-aad2-c001ae68c2e7
            Description:  Database service registration with db service name: CDBET015
                 Status:  Success
                Created:  March 2, 2022 12:01:50 PM CET
                Message:
 
Task Name                                Start Time                          End Time                            Status
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------
TDE parameter validate at destination    March 2, 2022 12:01:55 PM CET       March 2, 2022 12:01:55 PM CET       Success
Enable OMF parameters                    March 2, 2022 12:01:56 PM CET       March 2, 2022 12:01:56 PM CET       Success
Setting db character set                 March 2, 2022 12:01:56 PM CET       March 2, 2022 12:01:56 PM CET       Success
Move Spfile to right location            March 2, 2022 12:01:56 PM CET       March 2, 2022 12:02:05 PM CET       Success
Enable DbSizing Template                 March 2, 2022 12:02:05 PM CET       March 2, 2022 12:02:08 PM CET       Success
Copy Pwfile to Shared Storage            March 2, 2022 12:02:08 PM CET       March 2, 2022 12:02:09 PM CET       Success
Add Startup Trigger to Open all PDBS     March 2, 2022 12:02:09 PM CET       March 2, 2022 12:02:10 PM CET       Success
Running DataPatch                        March 2, 2022 12:02:10 PM CET       March 2, 2022 12:02:23 PM CET       Success
configuring TDE                          March 2, 2022 12:02:23 PM CET       March 2, 2022 12:02:25 PM CET       Success
Reset Associated Networks                March 2, 2022 12:02:26 PM CET       March 2, 2022 12:02:28 PM CET       Success
```

However this causes the TDE Wallet Management to be "EXTERNAL".

```
odacli describe-database -in CDB
…
  TDE Wallet Management: EXTERNAL
            TDE Enabled: true
…
```